# watch props update in a child created programmatically

Tags: vue.js

I created the child using:

```
const ComponentClass = Vue.extend(someComponent);
const instance = new ComponentClass({
    propsData: { prop: this.value }
})
instance.$mount();
this.$refs.container.appendChild(instance.$el);
```

When `this.value` is updated in the parent, its value doesn't change in the child. I've tried to watch it but it didn't work.

Comment: Could you maybe explain what the motivation is for creating component instances in this way? The standard way to do this, using either a template or a render function, would automatically propagate the changes. Without knowing the constraints that led to this unusual approach it's difficult to know what to suggest.

Comment: @skirtle: one use-case would be a dynamically generated form created from a config object with a fairly large number of possible elements that could be nested into any number of sub-levels. Besides, you want it to work with components that will be created in future updates and you want to simplify registering those components as much as possible. Are you going to use v-if's? Another usecase is writing mapbox popups or markers as vue components, so you don't keep their logic in the map component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

There's an easier way to achieve this:

- create a `<div>`
- append it to your `$refs.container`
- create a new Vue instance and `.$mount()` it in the div
- set the div instance's data to whatever you want to bind dynamically, getting values from the parent
- provide the props to the mounted component from the div's data, through render function

```js
methods: {
  addComponent() {
    const div = document.createElement("div");
    this.$refs.container.appendChild(div);
    new Vue({
      components: { Test },
      data: this.$data,
      render: h => h("test", {
        props: {
          message: this.msg
        }
      })
    }).$mount(div);
  }
}
```

**Important note:** `this` in `this.$data` refers the parent (the component which has the `addComponent` method), while `this` inside `render` refers `new Vue()`'s instance. So, the chain of reactivity is: `parent.$data` > `new Vue().$data` > `new Vue().render` => `Test.props`. I had numerous attempts at bypassing the `new Vue()` step and passing a `Test` component directly, but haven't found a way yet. I'm pretty sure it's possible, though, although the solution above achieves it in practice, because the `<div>` in which `new Vue()` renders gets replaced by its template, which is the `Test` component. So, in practice, `Test` is a direct ancestor of `$refs.container`. But in reality, it passes through an extra instance of Vue, used for binding.

Obviously, if you don't want to add a new child component to the container each time the method is called, you can ditch the `div` placeholder and simply `.$mount(this.$refs.container)`, but by doing so you will replace the existing child each subsequent time you call the method.

See it working here: https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-dhawan-9ed2l?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue

However, unlike the method below, you can't override data props of the child with values from parent dynamically. But, if you think about it, that's the way `data` ***should*** work, so just use `props` for whatever you want bound.

---

**Initial answer:**

Here's a function I've used over multiple projects, mostly for creating programmatic components for mapbox popups and markers, but also useful for creating components without actually adding them to DOM, for various purposes.

```js
import Vue from "vue";
// import store from "./store";

export function addProgrammaticComponent(parent, component, dataFn, componentOptions) {
  const ComponentClass = Vue.extend(component);
  const initData = dataFn() || {};
  const data = {};
  const propsData = {};
  const propKeys = Object.keys(ComponentClass.options.props || {});

  Object.keys(initData).forEach(key => {
    if (propKeys.includes(key)) {
      propsData[key] = initData[key];
    } else {
      data[key] = initData[key];
    }
  });

  const instance = new ComponentClass({
    // store,
    data,
    propsData,
    ...componentOptions
  });

  instance.$mount(document.createElement("div"));

  const dataSetter = data => {
    Object.keys(data).forEach(key => {
      instance[key] = data[key];
    });
  };

  const unwatch = parent.$watch(dataFn || {}, dataSetter);

  return {
    instance,
    update: () => dataSetter(dataFn ? dataFn() : {}),
    dispose: () => {
      unwatch();
      instance.$destroy();
    }
  };
}
```

`componentOptions` is to provide any custom (one-off) functionality to the new instance (i.e.: `mounted()`, watchers, computed, store, you name it...).

I've set up a demo here: https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-mestorf-297xx?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue

Notice I'm not doing the `appendChild` in the function purposefully, as in some cases I want to use the `instance` without adding it to DOM. The regular usage is:

```
const component = addProgrammaticComponent(this, SomeComponent, dataFn);
this.$el.appendChild(component.instance.$el);
```

Depending on what your dynamic component does, you might want to call `.dispose()` on it in parent's `beforeDestroy()`. If you don't, `beforeDestroy()` on child never gets called.

---

Probably the coolest part about it all is you don't actually need to append the child to the parent's DOM (it can be placed anywhere in DOM and the child will still respond to any changes of the parent, like it would if it was an actual descendant). Their *"link"* is programmatic, through `dataFn`.

Obviously, this opens the door to a bunch of potential problems, especially around destroying the parent without destroying the child. So you need be very careful and thorough about this type of cleanup. You either register each dynamic component into a property of the parent and `.dispose()` all of them in the parent's `beforeDestroy()` or give them a particular selector and sweep the entire DOM clean before destroying the parent.

Another interesting note is that in Vue 3 all of the above will no longer be necessary, as most of the core Vue functionality (reactivity, computed, hooks, listeners) is now exposed and reusable as is, so you won't have to `$mount` a component in order to have access to its *"magic"*.